# Existence of bijection that reorders elements?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, reference-request, proof-verification, lebesgue-measure

Suppose I have some function $f:\mathbb{R}\to[0,1]$. Does there necessarily exist a bijective mapping $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $g(x)\leq g(y)$ implies $f(x)≤f(y)$? If not, does it help if I restrict the domain to $\mathbb{R}_+$ or a closed interval?

**Edit:** I guess if I take a very ugly function such as the indicator function that is $1$ if and only if $x$ is rational, this may not hold. (In that case, let $x$ be any rational number. Whatever $g(x)$, the set $[g(x),\infty)$ has positive Lebesgue measure, but its pre-image wrt $g$ is countable.) But what about if I only need the properties to hold almost everywhere? Specifically, if the order condition holds except on a set of measure zero, if $\textsf{Im}(g)=\mathbb{R}$ up to a set of measure zero and $g^{-1}(z)$ has measure zero for all $z\in[0,1]$?

**Proof idea:** Here's my original intuition for what could work, but I'm not confident all arguments are sound.
Let $h$ correspond to some probability measure over $\mathbb{R}$ that has full support (by which I mean, if $h(A)=0$, then the set $A$ has Lebesgue measure zero - should I rather call this absolutely continuous?) and admits a distribution function $H$. Then let 
$$g(x)=H^{-1}(1-h(f^{-1}((f(x),\infty)))-h(f^{-1}(\{f(x)\})\cap(x,\infty)).$$

Furthermore, let $$A=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty\left\{\left(\frac{m}{n},\frac{m+1}{n}\right)\mid 0\leq m<n\text{ and }h\left(f^{-1}\left(\frac{m}{n},\frac{m+1}{n}\right)\right)=0\right\}.$$ Since $f^{-1}(A)$ can be written as a countable union of inverse images with zero measure each, it follows that $h(f^{-1}(A))=0$.

In that case, $f(x)<f(y)$ with $x,y\notin f^{-1}(A)$ implies $(f(x),\infty)\supseteq(f(y),\infty)\cup (\{f(y)\}\cap(x,\infty))\cup (f(x),f(y))$ and the inverse image of the last part of this disjoint union has nonzero measure by definition of $A$. This implies $g(x)<g(y)$, establishing the desired order condition.

As for bijectivity, let $z\in \mathbb{R}$. I want to show $h(g^{-1}(z))=0$. By the above, all points in $g^{-1}(z)\setminus A$ share a common function value $f(z)$. Let $(a,b)$ be the infimum and the maximum of $g^{-1}(z)$ respectively. By the definition of $g(\cdot)$, it must hold that $h(g^{-1}(z))\leq h(f^{-1}({f(z)})\cap(a,b))=0$. This establishes my notion of "almost everywhere injective".

Lastly, for surjectivity, let $k=H^{-1}(y)$ for any $y\in\mathbb{R}$. Set $z=\inf\{f(x)\mid h(f^{-1}((f(x),\infty)))<k\}$. Either $h(f^{-1}((z,\infty)))=k$ and $h(f^{-1}(\{z\}))=0$, or $h(f^{-1}((z,\infty)))>k$. Either way, there exists $x\in f^{-1}(\{z\})$ such that $g(x)=H^{-1}(k)$.

Does this sound plausible? Shouldn't there be a *much* more simple approach to prove this intuitive result?

Comment: I'm having trouble figuring out the most appropriate tags for this question, so if anybody has suggestions or edits regarding that, I'd be all ears. :)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. What happens if $f$ and $g$ are inverses? Surely then it is true? A fact you might find useful is that every bijection is monotone, and every monotone function is bijective between it's domain and range.

Comment: The thing is that I don't want to make assumptions on f. In particular, I don't want to assume it's invertible or monotone.

Answer (score 1):

If $f = 0$ you always have $fg(x) \leq fg(y)$, so such a $g$ does not always exist.

Comment: True. Sorry about that oversight. I will rewrite the question to avoid this issue. What I really want is simply a reshuffling of the elements so that function values become increasing. I guess the corresponding condition should be: "There exists a bijection $g$ such that $g(x)\leq g(y)$ implies $f(x)\leq f(y)$."
Can you advise me on whether I should accept your answer here and open a new question with the correct condition, or edit the one above?

Comment: Edit is ok, I guess. Then just ignore my answer :)